# Xamarin Forms Hangs on data load

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am creating a Xamarin app using MVVM and DI. I have successfully gotten MVVM and DI working but my issue is with loading data. When the app starts my view model gets injected into the view. In the constructor of the view model, it calls the below code:

```
  Task.Run(async () => 
  {
      MyDataBoundObject = await GetFromServer<SomeObjectType>("some URL");
  });

//----------------------------------------
public async Task<T> GetFromServer<T>(string url) //shorten version
{
    HttpClient httpClient = _httpClientFactpry.CreateClient("myClientName");

    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

    string responseJson = await  response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseJson);
}
```

In Visual Studio I load my data perfectly. However, once I deploy my app to an Android device the app hangs, the UI elements don't load on the View. I can see that my web api is getting called.

Is there something I am missing about loading data in Xamarin App when the View is loaded?

**UPDATE 0**

If I set a time out of 1ms the http request times out. However, if I set the time out to be 1s i do not get a timeout.

**UPDATE 1**

The API call works when I load another view and call the API via a button press.

**UPDATE 2**

I just finished debugging on the device. It seems like the HTTP request doesn't get returned to the device. I successfully complete the API request on the server, but the app doesn't seem to ever receive it. I have tried running the API request synchronously, and I get the same result.

**UPDATE 3**

Device Log take from just before the HTTP Request.

```
Type    Tag Message 
Info    AiAiEcho    Predicting[1]: { Feature:WEATHER, creation:2021-11-05T11:04:16.863Z, expiry:2021-11-05T17:04:16.863Z, isExpired: false} 
Debug   ConnectivityService NetReassign [no changes]    
Info    WifiHAL event received NL80211_CMD_VENDOR, vendor_id = 0x1374, subcmd = 0xd 
Info    WifiHAL event received NL80211_CMD_VENDOR, vendor_id = 0x1374, subcmd = 0xd 
Debug   ConnectivityService NetReassign [no changes]    
Info    WifiHAL event received NL80211_CMD_VENDOR, vendor_id = 0x1374, subcmd = 0xd 
Debug   CHRE    @ 39061.390: Nanoapp list request from client ID 1  
Verbose ContextHubHal   queryApps   
Debug   CHRE    @ 39061.380: Nanoapp list request from client ID 1  
Verbose ContextHubHal   queryApps   
Warning AppOps  Noting op not finished: uid 10022 pkg com.google.android.gms code 113 startTime of in progress event=1636106330032  
Debug   CHRE    @ 39061.359: Nanoapp list request from client ID 1  
Verbose ContextHubHal   queryApps   
Debug   CHRE    @ 39061.351: Nanoapp list request from client ID 1  
Verbose ContextHubHal   queryApps   
Info    CHRE    @ 39061.335: [NanoMinion] sent MSG Type 0x72, Version 0, 173 bytes, MessageId 3 
Info    CHRE    @ 39061.335: [AR] send to host, reason=3, sampleSize=10, transitionSize=0, lastAccelTime = 39042490, lastAudioTime = 0  
Info    CHRE    @ 39061.335: [AR] request.flush 
Info    CHRE    @ 39061.335: [NanoMinion] received MSG Type 0x70, Version 1, 6 bytes    
Debug   CHRE    @ 39061.335: Parsed nanoapp message from host: app ID 0x476f6f676c00100b, endpoint 0x3, msgType 112, payload size 10    
Verbose ContextHubHal   sendMessageToHub    
Debug   ConnectivityService NetReassign [no changes]    
Info    WifiHAL event received NL80211_CMD_VENDOR, vendor_id = 0x1374, subcmd = 0xd 
Info    WifiHAL event received NL80211_CMD_VENDOR, vendor_id = 0x1374, subcmd = 0xd 
Info    ContentCaptureManagerService    Content capture data sharing session terminated successfully for package 'com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox'  
Info    ContentCaptureManagerService    Content capture data sharing session terminated successfully for package 'com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox'  
Debug   ConnectivityService NetReassign [no changes]    
Info    WifiHAL event received NL80211_CMD_VENDOR, vendor_id = 0x1374, subcmd = 0xd 
Debug   ConnectivityService NetReassign [no changes]    
Info    WifiHAL event received NL80211_CMD_VENDOR, vendor_id = 0x1374, subcmd = 0xd 
Info    WifiHAL event received NL80211_CMD_VENDOR, vendor_id = 0x1374, subcmd = 0xd 
Debug   ConnectivityService NetReassign [no changes]    
Info    WifiHAL event received NL80211_CMD_VENDOR, vendor_id = 0x1374, subcmd = 0xd 
Debug   ConnectivityService NetReassign [no changes]    
Info    WifiHAL event received NL80211_CMD_VENDOR, vendor_id = 0x1374, subcmd = 0xd 
Info    WifiHAL event received NL80211_CMD_VENDOR, vendor_id = 0x1374, subcmd = 0xd 
Debug   ConnectivityService NetReassign [no changes]    
Info    CHRE    @ 39044.826: [AR] audiofusion:HandleIdleStateChange: state = 1  
Info    CHRE    @ 39044.818: [AR] ON => IDLE    
Info    WifiHAL event received NL80211_CMD_VENDOR, vendor_id = 0x1374, subcmd = 0xd 
Debug   ConnectivityService NetReassign [no changes]    
Info    WifiHAL event received NL80211_CMD_VENDOR, vendor_id = 0x1374, subcmd = 0xd 
Info    Authzen [DeviceStateSyncManager] The server is in sync with current state. Nothing to do    
Warning MdnsClient  Error while decoding multicast packet (825): 2  
Warning MdnsClient  Error while decoding multicast packet (824): 2  
Debug   InterruptionStateProvider   No bubble up: not allowed to bubble: 0|com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox|0|travis.pettry@gmail.com::a:snotification:[0x394,wx.f,NOTIFICATION]|10069   
Debug   InterruptionStateProvider   No alerting: suppressed due to group alert behavior 
Debug   InterruptionStateProvider   No alerting: suppressed due to group alert behavior 
Debug   InterruptionStateProvider   No bubble up: not allowed to bubble: 0|com.google.android.gm|0|gig:-976719110:CLASSIC_INBOX_ALL_MAIL|10113  
Debug   InterruptionStateProvider   No bubble up: not allowed to bubble: -1|android|62|null|1000    
Info    WifiHAL event received NL80211_CMD_VENDOR, vendor_id = 0x1374, subcmd = 0xd 
Debug   ConnectivityService NetReassign [no changes]    
Info    WifiHAL event received NL80211_CMD_VENDOR, vendor_id = 0x1374, subcmd = 0xd 
Debug   ConnectivityService NetReassign [no changes]    
Info    WifiHAL event received NL80211_CMD_VENDOR, vendor_id = 0x1374, subcmd = 0xd 
Warning BcSmartspaceCard    No title view to update 
Info    keystore2   keystore2::watchdog: Watchdog thread idle -> terminating. Have a great day. 
Warning BcSmartspaceCard    No title view to update 
Info    AiAiEcho    Ranked targets strategy: SORT, count: 1, ranking metadata: { cardId: WEATHER-1905757503, card type: WEATHER, update time: 2021-11-05T11:04:16.863Z, expiration time: 2021-11-05T17:04:16.863Z, ranking metadata: RankingMetaData(urgency=0.0, priority=0.0, recency=0.0, rankScore=0.0, importantTimePoints=# jle@7bca4) }
```

Thank you,
Travis

Comment: it would be helpful to know what `GetFromServer` is doing.  And have you tried debugging on the device, or looking at the logs, too see where the problem is?

Comment: Did you debug on the device? Are all your tasks completing successfull? `Task.Run` is not awaited, so exceptions go to nowhere. Are you on the UI Thread when you update your Databound Item (not sure it that's still required)?

Comment: @Jason I have updated the post with the device debugging.

Comment: Hi @TravisPettry,  could you please post the log about this problem?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I have added the device log.

Comment: I think `Task.Run` must be awaited. Otherwise UI not affected by fetched data and it doesn't update components or etc.

Comment: @Batuhan I now running sync instead of running in a Task.Run

Comment: @TravisPettry still hanging ?

Comment: @Batuhan yes it is

Comment: Could you please post more code snippets or a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can help you better？